# How to count a contentious repeation of a charcater in a string

Tags: sql

I have string like this `'LLLLLLLNNNNNNNLLLLLL'`

In this I want put a condition for repetition of 'L' five times then it return a value '1'.

I want SQL query for this

Comment: Just use like -- `field like '%LLLLL%`

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN field LIKE '%LLLLL%' THEN '1' ELSE field END
```

Comment: And? its a small questions that requires a small snippet of code. by adding `Use a like statement` or something similar, im not adding anything to the answer. Anyone, OP included, can see that its a simple statement, no explanation needed.